# Triangle Bisectors

Tags: geometry

Triangle ABC is an equilateral triangle and O is the center of its inscribed circle. If the area of the circle is $4\pi$ sq cm, what is the area, in square centimeters, of triangle ABC? Express your answer in simplest radical form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Show that, if $r$ is the radius of the inscribed circle, then the area of the triangle is $A=3\sqrt{3}r^2$. (Use the fact that the height of the triangle is $3r$).

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ be the area of the triangle, $b$ its side length, $h$ its height, $r$ the radius of the circle. With the area of the circle you can find $r$. Using that $(\frac{b}{2})^2 + h^2 = b^2$ and that $h=r+\sqrt{(\frac{b}{2})^2+r^2}$ (can you see why?), you can find $h$ as a function of $b$ and then $b$ as a function of $r$, hence you already have everything, since $S=bh/2$.